# In App purchase in iOS suddenly stop working ( Error code=5002 occurred )

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have integrated in-App purchase in my application successfully. I tested it properly by making test user account in itunes. My in-app purchase worked fine. But suddenly my IAP stopped working.

App can load all of the products but after entering my account credentials then transection queue undergoes state `SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed` and gives an error

> Error Domain=SSServerErrorDomain Code=5002 "An unknown error has occurred"

Comment: the unknown errors are the worst. is it a temporary error or it is happening permanently?

Comment: I just got the same error again and again...

Comment: @holex , It seems to be permanent now

Comment: store kit has stopped working on simulator. It Is running on device

Comment: Latest docs now say:
"Note: Store Kit can be tested in the iOS Simulator, except for hosted content downloads."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been stopped working on simulator. try to use it on real device. It will work fine.

Answer (score 50):

It seems that the storekit does not work in the simulator any longer. I quote from storekit docs:

> Note: Store Kit does not operate in iOS Simulator. When running your
>   application in iOS Simulator, Store Kit logs a warning if your
>   application attempts to retrieve the payment queue. Testing the store
>   must be done on actual devices.

[Store Kit Docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/DevelopingwithStoreKit/DevelopingwithStoreKit.html)

Comment: 2 days of banging my head against the wall and i find this. Thanks.

Comment: That's a total bummer. It used to not work, then it did for awhile and now it doesn't? And the best they can do is give us Unknown Error 5002??? That's the biggest crime of all.

Comment: Can anyone confirm if this is now possible? Store Kit Docs at the link above seem to be updated saying "Note: Store Kit can be tested in the iOS Simulator, except for hosted content downloads."

Comment: Even Better, Xcode 5 & iOS 7, no error at all, it just doesn't ever call the delegate.  ugh

Answer (score 4):

If you are testing on real device, make sure it is not JB.
If you are testing on simulator, make sure you are running iOS 6.0 or above, lower version of simulator doesn't work, I wasted a whole day to figure this out...

Comment: That's what is happening now with me. Working on simulator 6.0 and not on 5.0. How did you figure it out? Cause I don't have a lot of devices with many IOS version. I need to be sure.

Comment: Note: Store Kit can be tested in the iOS Simulator, except for hosted content downloads. Apple Docs

Comment: I experienced the same issue. It was driving me crazy! Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into the same error on iOS Simulator, but it works on my device(iPhone 3G).

The error is returned from Apple's Server, it's not under control by us.

Answer (score 0):

Facing the same problem in ios 5.1 the store kit dosent work on simulator anymore you need to check it in the device.

And even after connecting to the device say you get an error code "Cannot connect to iTunes Store"

then that means that your device cannot contact the apple store and that is something which is not your fault.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, sign out of any existing account in the Settings app on your device.