# inapp purchase - An unknown error has occurred - 5002 error code - iOS5

Tags: iphone, ios, in-app-purchase, ios5

On ios5 simulator, I am trying to test my in app purchase using test account. when i tried to do test purchase ,it prompted to me to enter app-store credentials. i entered my test account credentials.

but i get the

> error as **An unknown error has occurred** and the error code i got is
>   5002

.

i deleted all the contents from my simulator ,cleaned the build no use.i also created new test user account but it doesnot work.

please let me know

Comment: the inAppPurchase process **is not** working on the Simulator but on the real device only.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11558929/in-app-purchase-in-ios-suddenly-stop-working-error-code-5002-occurred

Answer (score 2):

If you are testing your app on simulator then you will get following error.

**Error Domain=SSServerErrorDomain Code=5002 "An unknown error has occurred" UserInfo=0x80ca070 {NSLocalizedDescription=An unknown error has occurred}**

Because, store-kit doesn't work on simulator. If you want to test your InApp Purchase then you must have to test on real **iOS device** not on **simulator**.

You can find more details from [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/DevelopingwithStoreKit/DevelopingwithStoreKit.html)

Comment: true, doesn't work on sim5.x but DOES work on sim6.x, maybe apple enabled this later on?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to test In-App purchases from the iOS Simulator as documented in the [StoreKit documentation provided by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Introduction.html).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Rachcha do you read questions when you moderate answers? This answer is valid.

Comment: @bahrep- this is a valid comment instead of a valid answer. I read both the question and the answer and found that you could even post your content in a better way as a comment and flag the question if it is not valid enough to you. Posting such content as an answer is, according to me, not the best thing to do in such cases.