# Ti.Storekit Titanium

Tags: javascript, ios, titanium, in-app-purchase, storekit

I'm having an issue with the Storekit module in Titanium when buying a subscription based item (probably affects other items as well).

The error code that I get when buying the item is:

```
[WARN] error in transaction: Error Domain=SSServerErrorDomain Code=5002 "An unknown error has occurred" UserInfo=0x9b3a660 {NSLocalizedDescription=An unknown error has occurred}
```

The code that I am using to reference the product is here: (Javascript)

```
requestProduct('553XXXXXX.testproductname', function (product) {
    var buySingleItem = Ti.UI.createButton({
        title: 'Buy ' + product.title + ', ' + product.formattedPrice,
        top: 60, left: 5, right: 5, height: 40
    });
    buySingleItem.addEventListener('click', function () {
        purchaseProduct(product);
    });
    win.add(buySingleItem);
});
```

Some notes:

```
Tested with iPad Simulator and iPhone 4S running 5.1.1
Module is called Ti.Storekit version 1.5 
Titanium SDK version is 2.1.1
```

Comment: The sample is incomplete. You don't include any of your calls to Ti.Storekit, making solving your issue a rather difficult task.

Comment: I take back what I said, it seems to work if you do it on the device. Although I still have issues.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot test in-app purchases using StoreKit in the simulator: [refer to this documentation:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/DevelopingwithStoreKit/DevelopingwithStoreKit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH103-SW1)

> Note: Store Kit does not operate in iOS Simulator. When running your
>   application in iOS Simulator, Store Kit logs a warning if your
>   application attempts to retrieve the payment queue. Testing the store
>   must be done on actual devices.

Also refer to this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11558929/in-app-purchase-in-ios-suddenly-stop-working-error-code-5002-occurred).

Comment: I've already noted that hence saying that I also tested with a physical device.

Comment: You shouldnt be testing this on a simulator at all as it seems to confuse Apple's servers in my experience. Have you tried deleting the product on iTunes Connect then remaking it? Is your app status in iTunes Connect "Waiting for Upload"?

Comment: Yeah I get the status Prepare for Upload and for the in app purchase button I have the status Ready to Submit.